# Does anyone "has" or "have"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number

I have read a similar question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23218/anyone-has-or-anyone-have-seen-them) but that one talks about the usage of has/have with reference to "anyone". Here, I wish to ask a question of the form:

> Does anyone has/have a black pen?

What is the correct form of verb which should be used here? I understand that for "anyone", it should be has, as in:

> Has anyone got a black pen?

But my doubt here is because of the auxilliary "does" in the question. Will that cause any change to the choice of has/have?

Comment: People with similar doubt might find this question on EL&U [Difference between “does have” and “has”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64487/difference-between-does-have-and-has) important and helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using auxillary or helping verbs, the first verb is conjugated according to subject, but the second part of it is fixed.

Take present progressive tense, for an example:

> I am going to the park.
>
> He is going to the park.
>
> We are going to the park.

The basic construction here is {to be} + {-ing form of verb}.  The {to be} is conjugated according to subject, but not its helping verb - it'll always be "going" in this example.

This is the same with {to do} + {plain form of verb}, which is the emphatic form of a verb, and often used for negative and interrogative expressions.

> I do go to the park from time to time.
>
> He does go to the park from time to time.
>
> Do you go to the park from time to time?
>
> Does he go to the park from time to time?
>
> Does anyone go to the park from time to time?

*Anyone* is singular, so the *first* verb is conjugated accordingly, but not any subsequent helping verb.

Answer (score 9):

The correct sentence would be :

> Does anyone have a black pen?

I would recommend not trying to follow rules blindly (might I add, like a robot) and give your intuition a voice too.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone, in this instance, is not plural. So, just substitute a name, "Does John ____ a black pen?" The answer is "have." However, the point is moot when one considers the more acceptable form (picture a classroom setting), "Who here has a black pen?" Mary might answer, "Jane has one." Jane might answer, "I have one." While to the original form, "Does anyone have a black pen" the literal answer could be "Yes, of course."