# Does anyone has a dog in "their" home

Tags: dummy-pronouns

I have read [this ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74382/does-anyone-has-or-have) and [this ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23218/anyone-has-or-anyone-have-seen-them) but I still don't understand how to use this one:

> Does anyone has a dog in **their** home?

Should I use *their* or something else?

Comment: The home belongs to them, therefore it is **their** home. It should be **have** since anyone is plural

Comment: Yes, it's fine. You could also use ***his** home, **her** home*, or ***his/her** home*, but using "singular they" has always been quite natural in English - ***and*** it avoids calling attention to possible "sexist" use of language.